# In proteus i am not able to find the memory browser as i found in the STM32 IDE

Tags: simulation, proteus

Please look the STM32 IDE screenshot:
[image]

Please look the Proteus screenshot:
[image]

As you can see proteus option after the simulation i didn't any memory option.

Please help to find this option .

[image]

Comment: Those familiar with the CubeIDE may know, but rather than showing a menu for access to the "memory browser", it may be better to to show the actual browser (not just a blank window) or simply describe its function, or what you need it for.  This is clearly an X-Y problem. Even if Proteus supports similar functionality, it is unlikely that it will use the same name for that.  It sounds like the sort of facility that would be provided by a debugger, and therefore accessible during a debug session (perhaps not _after_ a simulation).

Comment: Your third screenshot which was not visible previously due to bad mark-up until I edited it, shows options for RAM/ROM/FLASH. Are those not what you are looking for?  As I said, it is an X-Y problem; you should ask about what you want the tool to do/show rather than ask about a feature of an entirely different tool. That reduces your audience from all Proteus users, to just Proteus users familiar with CubeIDE.